# C# Nunit Assert with try..catch

Tags: c#, logging, nunit, try-catch, assert

I started using extent reports and creating my tests so I can run using nunit but also log everything into a nice report .  I came by this example in the docs. http://extentreports.relevantcodes.com/net/docs.html#nunit-selenium-example. The example with assert traps the exception but throws again for nunit to catch but also logs.

```
try
{
    Assert.AreEqual(true, isFound);
    test.Log(LogStatus.Pass, "Search button displayed");
}
catch (AssertionException ex)
{
    test.Log(LogStatus.Fail, "<pre>" + ex.StackTrace + "</pre>");
    throw;
}
```

its  a simple example..but i wonder. What other ways can we log and assert at the same time? Is try catch the only way?

Comment: Console output is typically captured and included in the test results, as is any failure information. It seems like you should be able to just log to the console and then parse the test results to generate whatever report you need.

Comment: Thanks.  Do you think there is a better approach then above to trap exceptions and log them?

Comment: please don't **[cross post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)**: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/289356/22815

Comment: @Karthik: Since the logging framework will automatically add the failure information to the test results, I wouldn't recommend doing the `try/catch/log` at all. I'd just use the information that the test framework captures.

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to use extent reports because it creates a very good dashboard to show daily results to mgmt and team. So I guess if I have to use it, try-catch is the most elegant solution available?